# Meteorjs Reactjs Enzyme test inline functions

Tags: reactjs, meteor, enzyme

I'm using Meteor in the backend and React in the frontend.

The Following Component simply takes every Element from the MongoCollection TestCollection and displays the data using a Component called ListElement. I'm using the package  `TrackerReact` to update my List Component everytime the Collection Updates

```
export default class List extends TrackerReact(Component){

 displayCollection(){
     return TestCollection.find({}).fetch().map((element)=>
         <ListElement key={element._id} name={element.name} />
   );
 }

 render(){
        <div className="main">
            {displayCollection()}
        </div>

  }

}
```

Next I want to test the Component by adding test data into the collection and checking that ListElements are added to my list using Enzyme

```
describe('<List />', () => {
 it('Test', () => {
   const wrapper = mount(<List>);
   // check component content
   expect(wrapper.find("div.main")).to.have.length(1);

   // insert dummy date to Collection
   StubCollections.add([TestCollection]);
   StubCollections.stub();
   TestCollection.insert({name:" marko"});
   expect(TestCollection.find().count()).to.equal(1);

   //Test Output
   console.log(wrapper.find("div.main").text());
   console.log(wrapper.find("div.main").html());
   });

});
```

The Problem I have how, is that my Test Output show no value for the text()  function and the html() only return:

```
            <div className="main"> </div>
```

How can I test it properly?